# Сохранить достижения игры в Google

Tags: java, google-play

Занимаюсь разработкой простого тайм-киллера. По мере прохождения, игрок будет получать баллы, по которым необходимо строить таблицу лидеров, а также таблицу лидеров среди друзей игрока. Не хочется для этого поднимать и содержать отдельный сервак. Может, если возможность как-то сохранять баллы в гугл сервисах?

Comment: Я на их сайте такие статьи нашел: [SavedGames](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) (если нужно прогресс игрока сохранять) и [Leaderboards](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards). Похоже на то что требуется